# ASP.Net Core website stops responding after receiving a bunch of requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I'm encountering the following problem in production with an ASP.Net Core website that runs InProc on IIS. The installed .Net Core runtime is 2.2.8.

Following a push notification on Signalr, my clients are sending about a hundred requests to a particular URL, which is bound to a controller method that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost()]
[Route("Api/GetData")]
public string[] GetData()
```

After serving a few requests, the server suddenly stops responding for a few minutes, before serving all the responses at once. No errors can be seen in the app logs, and the IIS logs shows huge response times for the requests.

I have enabled [Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) in IIS to analyse requests that take longer than 9 seconds and I see that the requests that take forever to respond are actual promptly processed by IIS.

E.g:

- IIS log: 47952ms

> 2020-05-12 12:18:15 169.XXX.XXX.XXX POST /Api/GetData - 443 -
>   195.XXX.XXX.XXX Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko
>   200 0 0 79479 945 **47952**

- IIS Failed Request Tracing logs:

[image: Failed Request Tracing log]

I haven't used IIS Failed Request Tracing before and I'm not sure how I should interpret this. I first though of a lock in the code, but I haven't found it and I'm not sure how it would also affect requests to other URLs? What's your thoughts?

*A maybe important note is that the clients are behind a proxy, so the server sees the same IP for them all. We have never encountered this issue before on another server.*

**UPDATE**: We managed to reproduce the problem with a version of `GetData()` that simply returns a static array of string. We found that the size of the array mattered. We reproduced the issue with a response of 88KB, but not with a small one (2.5K). Looking at the .net core logs, it seems that the result of the method is computed promptly, but the response itself is hanging (we haven't figured out why). **Upgrading to .Net Core 3.1 solved the problem...**
I'm keeping the question open in case somebody can provide an explanation.

Comment: Do you have any async/await code?  It sounds to me like it's blocking.

Comment: Do you wait for something in your `GetData[]` (for example for a data from the database)? Maybe processing takes too long.

Comment: The image you post didn't show the root cause. The whole processes logged in your FRT log are finished in 1 second. Please go to log->request details->performance view and click view trace. Please post the process that take 9 seconds.

Comment: That's the thing, there are none. They all show 0ms

Comment: Have you tried to set highest log level and check error messages?